# How can I update the timezone tables in ICU4J JAR?

Tags: timezone, icu4j

I've been periodically using the [ICUTZU tool](https://sourceforge.net/projects/icu/files/OldFiles/icu_tools), which is a tool to update the timezone tables in ICU4J.  The tool is supposed to find the latest version of the timezone database online.  Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be working anymore.   The tool currently shows the latest version as 2018g, which is the version shipped with the tool.

I believe I understand the process of updating the tables without the tool, but maybe I know just enough to be dangerous.  I have not found any good documentation to describe the process.

I found the files that I need to insert into the JARs in our product which contain ICU4J [here](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu-data/tree/main/tzdata/icunew/2023a/44/be).

The tool hasn't been updated since 2018?  Has the method of updating the timezone database in ICU4J changed?  Or is the tool broken?

What I tried:

- I downloaded ICUTZU 1.6.0 (circa de 2018), which seems to be the latest copy, and unzipped it
- To run it, I enter **java -jar icutzu.jar**, which starts the GUI.
- I search the directory of the product that I want to update.
- It finds the JARs that contain ICU4J and offers to update them with TZ version 2018g (5 years old).
- The drop down list should contain the most recent version which is 2023c.  The tool is supposed to download the latest version from the internet.